# K3b does not read blank CD after upgrade from ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, burning, k3b

I upgraded my Ubuntu to the latest 12.10 through the software update, and it updated fine.

Now when I try to burn Cd's, it seems like it can not read the blank disc.

I'm using K3B. Before the update it was fine, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Gnome automounts blank CDs and automatically formats them. I do not know how to disable this, but here is a work around : use KDE !

1. install KDE :

   sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop libk3b6-extracodecs
2. logout
3. select KDE
4. login again

Comment: Its not related to Gnome or KDE. Rather to some configuration issues.. One must not switch the Desktop environment for these kinds of issues unless he want to give it a try. switching to KDE won't help !